# Windows Azure: How to process the SAML token returned by ACS in java

Tags: azure, azure-acs

I configured identity provider and Relying party application in ACS and i see that ACS is sending SAML token to my return URL

Now the question is: How do i process the SAML token in java , validate it and extract the claims?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [Cloud Ninja for Java](https://github.com/PersistentSys/cloudninja-for-java), a reference app demonstrating how to build multi-tenant applications in Windows Azure with Java.

If you look at the TenantProvisioning app, you'll see [ACSAuthenticationHelper.java](https://github.com/PersistentSys/cloudninja-for-java/blob/master/TenantProvisioning/src/com/persistent/cloudninja/acs/ACSAuthenticationHelper.java), which is a good place to start, as it creates new tenants, sets up relying party, etc. You'll need to look at the TenantDashboard app to see how users are authenticated. Under the `utils` folder, you'll see [SAMLParser.java](https://github.com/PersistentSys/cloudninja-for-java/blob/master/TenantDashboard/src/com/persistent/cloudninja/utils/SAMLParser.java).

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not a Java programmer)

Have you tried [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) explained [here](http://www.capcourse.com/Library/OpenSAML/index.html)

As the ACS returns a valid SAML, you can process it with any SAML aware library.